# Pytorch on Ubuntu 22.04 wont finish installing

Tags: pytorch

Am running a t2.micro on AWS with Ubuntu and need to install Pytorch.
first I installed CUDA 12.3 and the NVIDIA 545 driver.
Then I want to install Pytorch with:

```
pip3 install torch torchvision torchaudio
```

[screenshot](https://i.stack.imgur.com/P62bb.png)

As you can see, it doesnt finish installing. If I leave it for a while, it cancels itself.

What's the best next step?

Tried installing it several times, did not work